# How can I speed up image transfer from my Android to the internet?

Tags: file-transfer, mobile-network, uploads

I have installed an app on my Android phone which can be used for uploading photos to the web. The problem is images can't be upload due to network weakness. Does anyone know a way in which I can speed up my uploads?

Answer (score 0):

The speed of an upload, or download, is determined by more than one factor, and can not simply be "increased". If the network connection is weak, there is little you can do about that. The speed will be determined by your upload speed, the receivers download speed, and how the communicating devices handle it all. As you are likely using wireless on your phone, things that can interfere with the wireless signal has also a lot to say. The more clear space is between you and the router, the better. Even then, other wireless devices can cause disturbance in the signal.

So the answer is, you really cam't, unless you know *exactly* what is slowing the speed down, and even then it is a gamble. What you can do is of course connect the phone to a computer, and upload the pictures manually from there. If the computer is connected to the net with wire, your pictures should take no time to upload/download ... unless you are on a 20 year old net line, that is...

Comment: thanks to response me, one more thing that can we run apk file via w7.

Comment: I sadly do not know of any way to do that, perhaps someone else do, tho.